# Trying to log with runit only returns 'unable to open supervise/ok'

Tags: debian, logging, runit

Installed `runit` in Debian 7.4 in a Vagrant.

My run script is working, but the moment I create a service/pants/log/ directory I start getting the following error: `unable to open supervise/ok`. My service continues to run but nothing gets logged.

I've tried two different services and both have the same issue.

I've tried various different service/pants/log/run scripts (mostly using svlogd), I've tried changing permissions on everything (a+rwx), the directory to store logs in exists and has the same permissions.

If I run svlogd straight off the commandline it works as expected.

The bash log below shows what happens as I rename `/etc/service/pants/_log` to `/etc/service/pants/log` and back again `/etc/service/pants/_log`.

```
root@vwb-debian-wheezy:/etc/service# sv s pants/
run: pants/: (pid 29260) 44931s
root@vwb-debian-wheezy:/etc/service# mv pants/{_,}log/
root@vwb-debian-wheezy:/etc/service# sv s pants/
run: pants/: (pid 29260) 44963swarning: pants/: unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist
; run: log: (pid 29260) 44963s
root@vwb-debian-wheezy:/etc/service# cat pants/log/run
#!/bin/sh

exec svlogd -ttt /var/log/service/pants/

root@vwb-debian-wheezy:/etc/service# ll pants/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jul  3 07:00 log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  442 Jul  3 06:58 run
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jul  2 18:59 supervise
root@vwb-debian-wheezy:/etc/service# ll /var/log/service/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jul  2 16:55 pants
root@vwb-debian-wheezy:/etc/service# mv pants/{,_}log/
root@vwb-debian-wheezy:/etc/service# sv s pants/
run: pants/: (pid 29260) 45105s
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create the `run` files in `/etc/sv/pants/` not `/etc/service/pants/`.

Then a symlink should be created in `/etc/service` to `/etc/sv/pants` to activate the service.

```
ln -s /etc/sv/pants /etc/service/
```

While creating the files directly in `/etc/service` works for just the service, it seems to cause problems when using logging as well.

A service can be deactivated by deleting the symlink in `/etc/service/`.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: I had the problem when upgrading sv services of a phusion/baseimage 0.9 to a 0.11 (ubuntu 18.04). This answer solved my :
```fatal: unable to open supervise/lock: file does not exist```
problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For the Debian installation, there are *two* directories: `/etc/service` and `/service`.  For your service to be effectively controlled, they should be more-or-less mirror images of each other.  In your example, for service `pants`, there should be a symlink `/etc/service/pants` and a symlink `/service/pants`, each should point to `/etc/sv/pants`.  You can "cheat" and make `/service` a symlink itself to `/etc/service` to get the same effect, but I'm not sure as of yet the full impact of that change.

Comment: On my Debian Wheezy install I have `/etc/sv/` not `/service/` as mentioned in my answer above. Ignoring that difference the outcome is the same.

Comment: So, after several days of fidgeting with it, it looks like a bug (typo?) in `/etc/runit/2`, where runsvdir is called with `/service` instead of `/etc/service`.  I just switched it to `/etc/service` and didn't bother with the /service symlink, and it appears happy.

Comment: @AveryPayne Thanks for this answer, I was having the same issue and the symlink worked for me. I'm surprised more people aren't running into this issue and voting this question and answer up.

Comment: It's been a little bit since I posted the answer.  After awhile, I didn't care about a symlink floating around in `/` that much so I went ahead and `ln -s /etc/service /service`, and let the runsvdir in `/etc/runit/2` point to it.  It's still happy.  Only issue I've run into is writing up all of the `/etc/sv` scripts needed to get things rolling.  But, "it's a good kind of hurt" :) since I've learned a bit more about init, services, debian's version of SysV scripts, etc. in the process.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running ubuntu 18.04 or higher and getting the following error

> unable to open supervise/ok: file does not exist

or if the runsvdir is not showing up in "grep" output then please **runit-systemd** package by running the following command

```
sudo apt install runit-systemd
```

For ubuntu 18.04 all the above specified answers did not worked for me. I have then found this solution from another askubuntu [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046836/how-to-properly-setup-runit-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I hope this helps

Comment: This is the answer. Just used it on Debian 10.